# How to set date mask in fields

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

How can I set mask on date fields, date from and date to.
Here is my code below

```
            <div class="col-md-6">
            Year_from
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.yfrom, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "10", minlength="4" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            Year_to 
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.yto, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "10", minlength = "4" })
        </div>

        <script>
            jQuery(function ($) {
                $("#yfrom").mask("99.99.9999");
                $("#yto").mask("99.99.9999");
            });

            var v = this.value;
            if (v.match(/^\d{2}$.) !== null) {
                this.value = v + '.';
            } else if (v.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$.) !== null) {
                this.value = v + '.'; 
            }
        </script>
    </div>
```

I tried to include jQuery function to this, but still not working, I need something that would show error on date field when someone input wrong values in first field and switch to another one.

Comment: Can you post whole script?

Comment: @Jayr That's what I have from my script, I tried with that but not working for me.

Comment: are you using jQuery mask plugin?

Comment: @saidfagan No i don't use it

Comment: Then why do you expect your code to work? Try using jQuery mask plugin.